# How to exclude product vendors from search results by customer tags

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to exclude products based on their vendor type for each customer tag. For example, if a customer is signed in and tagged as 'designer' they should only gets products from vendor type 'designer' in the search results.

I put the code below inside of {% if search.performed %} but it isn't doing the trick. Thanks in advance.

```
    {% assign isWholesaler = false %}
          {% if customer %}
            {% if customer.tags contains 'wholesale' %}
              {% assign isWholesaler = true %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
          
          {% if isWholesaler %}
            {% for result in search.results %}
                {% if item.product.vendor == 'CompanyName Wholesale' %}
                {% include 'search-result' %}
                {% else %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}

    {% assign isDesigner = false %}
          {% if customer %}
            {% if customer.tags contains 'designer' %}
              {% assign isDesigner = true %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}

          {% if isDesigner %}
            {% for item in search.results %}
                {% if item.product.vendor == 'CompanyName Designer' %}
                {% include 'search-result' %}
                {% else %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}

    {% assign isConsumer = false %}
          {% if customer %}
            {% if customer.tags contains 'consumer' %}
              {% assign isConsumer = true %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}

          {% if isConsumer %}
            {% for item in search.results %}
                {% if item.product.vendor == 'CompanyName' %}
                {% include 'search-result' %}
                {% else %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
```

Comment: What is the output that you are getting? Are no products being output from your loops? Or are products that shouldn't be output slipping through?

Comment: @kenput3r Products that shouldn't be output are slipping through.